# I seem unable to upgrade from 20.04 LTS to 22.04 LTS. when using do-release-upgrade

Tags: 20.04, upgrade, 22.04, lts, metadata

The machine is new, it's a Dell latitude 5300 with the default image of ubuntu 20.04 LTS
I changed `Prompt=never`  into `Prompt=lts` in  `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades`

I get

```
root@lat530-26:/etc/update-manager# do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Failed to connect to https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts. Check your Internet connection or proxy settings
There is no development version of an LTS available.
To upgrade to the latest non-LTS development release 
set Prompt=normal in /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades.
root@lat530-26:/etc/update-manager#
```

Very bizar, because wget downloads that file without problem:

```
root@lat530-26:/etc/update-manager# wget https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts
--2022-10-26 09:43:51--  https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts
Resolving changelogs.ubuntu.com (changelogs.ubuntu.com)... 185.125.190.17, 91.189.91.49, 91.189.91.48, ...
Connecting to changelogs.ubuntu.com (changelogs.ubuntu.com)|185.125.190.17|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 
Length: 5623 (5,5K)
Saving to: ‘meta-release-lts’

meta-release-lts                                     100%[=====================================================================================================================>]   5,49K  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

2022-10-26 09:43:51 (730 MB/s) - ‘meta-release-lts’ saved [5623/5623]

root@lat530-26:/etc/update-manager#
```

I also tried changing

`Prompt=lts`  into `Prompt=normal` in  `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades`

```
root@lat530-26:/etc/update-manager# do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Failed to connect to https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release. Check your Internet connection or proxy settings
No new release found.
root@lat530-26:/etc/update-manager#
```

like expected this doesn't change anything

Comment: Why are you trying to install a meta release?

Answer (score 1):

I assumed you have done a backup...

How about `sudo do-release-upgrade -d -f DistUpgradeViewGtk3` so you can have GUI to see what is going on, or `sudo update-manager -c` to initiate the upgrade.

Check the configuration of the update manager to see if it allows an update to occur, i.e. never, normal or LTS using `cat /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades`

Comment: Hi, I edited "/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades", and it was never, tried, both lts and normal like mentioned. I gave up/lost my patience and did a fresh install. I see if it reoccurs for a next machine.

Comment: -d looks for a pre release version so this will not work.

Comment: I think I may fully understand now why this wasn't working for him because there are things that do-release-upgrade do and not do depending on your kernel version and sources.list that require to be updated first prior to using do-release-upgrade otherwise it just updates your current system to the current version your already using as it were.  His current kernel was 5.4 I believe and the kernel version for 22.04 is 5.15  To get to the new kernel he needed to run "sudo apt-get linux-generic" followed by "sudo apt update" to update the sources.list I now presume.